Pairs of matrices for which traces of powers are independent of the order
Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices over ${\mathbb C}$ such that, for all $m,k$ and all partitions $(i_1,\ldots ,i_r)$ of $m$ and $(j_1,\ldots ,j_r)$ of $k$ (perhaps with some zero parts),
$${\rm tr}\, (A^{i_1}B^{j_1}\ldots A^{i_r}B^{j_r})={\rm tr}\, (A^mB^k),$$
i.e. traces of noncommuting monomials in $A$ and $B$ are independent of the order of terms. This holds for example if $A$ and $B$ generate a solvable Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ (since we can embed it in the upper-triangular matrices, and then it is clear), but it fails for $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, where ${\rm tr}(A^2B^2)=0$ but ${\rm tr}(ABAB)=1$.
Question: is it true that the above condition on equality of traces holds only if $A,B$ generate a solvable Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$?

If you look at the book of Radjavi on Simultaneous Triangularization it is shown that a semigroup of complex matrices which satisfies your trace property is simultaneously triangularizable, and so they generate an upper triangular associative algebra.  It should then follow that the Lie algebra is solvable.
The original paper is Heydar Radjavi, A TRACE CONDITION EQUIVALENT TO SIMULTANEOUS TRIANGULARIZABILITY,  Can. J. Math., Vol. XXXVIII, No. 2, 1986, pp. 376-386.

The proof roughly is that you can put the representation in block upper triangular form with irreducible reps on the diagonal and any irreducible algebra over C is all matrices and these don't satisfy the trace property unless they are 1x1

Very nice. Do you know of a similar characterization for simultaneous triangularization of three or more matrices?

@AbdelmalekAbsesselam, This characterization works for any number of matrices.  It’s about the semigroup they generate.

my bad, just opened the article you cited and indeed it's for general collections instead of just pairs.

Great, thanks for the answer. The argument is quite straightforward and I suspect it might have appeared earlier (in the context of Lie algebras rather than semigroups), but this is the answer I wanted. Another consequence (I think) is that this condition on the trace holds if and only if the commutator bracket of $A$ and $B$ is nilpotent.

If you look at the top of page 379 of the linked paper he says McCoy proved in 1936 that A,B are simultaneously triangularizable iff the commutator is nilpotent and then generalizes to semigroups

@PaulLevy If you're happy with this answer, don't forget to accept it.

@Benjamin Steinberg, "A,B are simultaneously triangularizable iff the commutator is nilpotent" is valid only when n=2.

@loupblanc, sorry I had misread page 379.  You are correct
